# YouTube subscribe button tooltip flashes over and over on Firefox when on a Bootstrap modal box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I've got an odd one here guys, all I've done is include a standard YouTube subscribe button on a **Bootstrap 3** modal box and on **Firefox 45.0.2** the tooltip goes crazy and flashes over and over (on and off) incrementing its z index over and over again.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/djhxLk59/1/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Youtube Subscribe Bootstrap 3 Modals</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="; return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch demo modal using data-toggle
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick='$("#myModal").modal("show"); return false;'>
   Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This is a test to show how the Youtube Subscribe button doesn't work on Firefix</p>
                <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
                <p><span id="youtube-follow-circle"></span>Subscribe on <span>YouTube</span>
                <br />    
                </p>
                <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

                <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="britneyspears" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see here that when you hover over the YouTube button the tooltip goes nuts.

This jsfiddle works fine on Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Interestingly, when I open the modal as soon as the page is loaded, as in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/od4eo13m/

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

then the YouTube tooltip works fine!

I am so confused here, it's driving me nuts.

Would love any hints please.

Kind regards, Jason.

Comment: tooltip works fine for me in the given JSFiddle.

Comment: @Mike hi mike, thanks, what version of Firefox did u try it on? If it worked the first time refresh the page a few times and try it, I should have mentioned its intermittent sometimes.

Comment: firefox 38.0, chrome 43.0 . both seem to work fine. Your code snippet here is not showing the subscribe button though.

Comment: @mike thanks, I will try and install those versions of Firefox and see if I get the same result, but it definitely is failing for me on the latest version. Yeah, I'll fix up the snippet in the morning. I think it's also failing on Microsoft Edge.